# How to remove blur effect on the image when user touch the image

Tags: ios, swift

In my application there are two option blur and Unblur image by touch the image. I am doing this to blur the Image when user touch the image

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    var croppedImg: UIImage? = nil
    let touch = touches.first
    var currentPoint = touch!.location(in: imgBackground)
    let ratioW: Double = Double(imgBackground.image!.size.width / imgBackground.frame.size.width)
    let ratioH: Double = Double(imgBackground.image!.size.height / imgBackground.frame.size.height)
    currentPoint.x *= CGFloat(ratioW)
    currentPoint.y *= CGFloat(ratioH)
    
    let circleSizeW = 25 * ratioW
    let circleSizeH = 25 * ratioH
    
    
   currentPoint.x = CGFloat((Double(currentPoint.x ) - circleSizeW / 2 < 0) ? 0 : Double(currentPoint.x ) - circleSizeW / 2)
    currentPoint.y = CGFloat((Double(currentPoint.y ) - circleSizeH / 2 < 0) ? 0 : Double(currentPoint.y ) - circleSizeH / 2)
    
    
    let cropRect = CGRect(x: currentPoint.x , y: currentPoint.y , width: CGFloat(circleSizeW), height: CGFloat(circleSizeH))
    
    
    croppedImg = croppIngimage(byImageName: imgBackground?.image, to: cropRect)
    
    // Blur Effect
    croppedImg = croppedImg?.imageWithGaussianBlur9()
    
   
    croppedImg = roundedRectImage(from: croppedImg, withRadious: 4)
    imgBackground.image = addImage(to: imgBackground.image, withImage2: croppedImg, andRect: cropRect)
}

func imageWithGaussianBlur9() -> UIImage? {
    // Blur horizontally

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, _: false, _: scale)
    draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha:  0.5)
    for x in 1..<5 {
        draw(in: CGRect(x: CGFloat(x), y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 0.5)
        draw(in: CGRect(x: CGFloat(-x), y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha:  0.5)
    }
    let horizBlurredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    // Blur vertically
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, _: false, _: scale)
    horizBlurredImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha:  0.5)
    for y in 1..<5 {
        horizBlurredImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(y), width: size.width, height: size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha:  0.5)
        horizBlurredImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(-y), width: size.width, height: size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha:  0.5)
    }
    let blurredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    //
    return blurredImage
}
```

The above code works perfectly when we blur the image

What should I do when user want to remove the blur effect

Comment: "What should I do when user want to remove the blur effect" You should replace the blurred image with the unblurred image. (Incidentally, your way of blurring is inefficient and unnecessary. Gaussian blur is built in, so why not just use it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to place 2 UIImageView over each other. In the bottom you have to place original image.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgBackground:UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomViewImage:UIImageView! // original image
```

Add below code for unblur the image -:

```
 var croppedImg: UIImage? = nil
    let touch = touches.first
    var currentPoint = touch!.location(in: imgBackground)
    let ratioW: Double = Double(imgBackground.image!.size.width / imgBackground.frame.size.width)
    let ratioH: Double = Double(imgBackground.image!.size.height / imgBackground.frame.size.height)
    currentPoint.x *= CGFloat(ratioW)
    currentPoint.y *= CGFloat(ratioH)
    
    let circleSizeW = 25 * ratioW
    let circleSizeH = 25 * ratioH
    
    
    currentPoint.x = CGFloat((Double(currentPoint.x ) - circleSizeW / 2 < 0) ? 0 : Double(currentPoint.x ) - circleSizeW / 2)
    currentPoint.y = CGFloat((Double(currentPoint.y ) - circleSizeH / 2 < 0) ? 0 : Double(currentPoint.y ) - circleSizeH / 2)
    
    
    let cropRect = CGRect(x: currentPoint.x , y: currentPoint.y , width: CGFloat(circleSizeW), height: CGFloat(circleSizeH))
croppedImg = croppIngimage(byImageName: bottomViewImage?.image, to: cropRect)
    croppedImg = roundedRectImage(from: croppedImg, withRadious: 4)
     imgBackground.image = addImage(to: imgBackground.image, withImage2: croppedImg, andRect: cropRect)
```